# Program won't execute pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have to design a multi-threaded application involved with the consumer-producer problem. So far, I've been trying to get the Pthreads to work correctly before I try to implement my solution. But, my program won't even load up the the function on my pthread. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* Producer(void *arg)
{
    printf("\nEntered Producer\n");
    int i, item, index;

    index = (int)arg;

    FILE *f = fopen(bookorders, "r");
    char c = fgetc(f);
    int z =0;
    while (c!=EOF) {
        char * buffer = (char *)malloc(1000);
        while (c!='\n') {
            *(buffer+z) = c;
            z++;
            c = fgetc(f);
        }

        char delim[2] = "|";
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }



}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t Produc;

    pthread_create(&Produc, NULL, Producer, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess my big question is what is the proper process of creating a pthread and then getting it to run a function, which in this case is my Producer function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is your main thread calls `pthread_create` and just returns and since the main thread exits, your Production thread also exits. What you need to do is, instruct the main thread to wait for the `Produc` thread to finish executing.

```
 int main(){
      //Call pthread_create
      pthread_join(Produc, NULL) ;
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Also, remember that, if you have multiple threads to create then write pthread_create for all threads first and then call pthread_join on all of them.